# InputBox Function For Combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am using VB.NET and would like to prompt the user to select from a list of options. Is there any way to easily do this similarly to the InputBox function?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: when do you want it? on click event of button?

Comment: @AshReva I am writing an add-in for Microsoft Project. When a button is pressed in the ribbon, some code is executed. I would like it to open at a certain point in that code. I need to be able to create it, populate the possible values (they are calculated), and prompt the user on the fly, similar to the functionality offered by the InputBox function.

Comment: @Andrew ComboBox, only one option should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

On selectedIndexchange event of combobox write following code

```
Dim comboBox As comboBox = CType(sender, comboBox)


if combBox.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
     Messagebox.show("please select something")
else
      ' your logic

End If
```